# move element to top when click each buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list and each list has "move top" button.
when click "move top" button, div element shoul be move to top(in DOM).

But I am getting little trouble to make it.

Also when using keyboard tabbing to the button and press enter key, the focus has to be keep to the button, after press the keyboard enter.

This is what I tried so far here
Please help.

```js
$('.btnTop').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().prepend(this).focus();
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap"> 
  <div id="aa" class="box">
    aa <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
  <div id="bb" class="box">
    bb <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
  <div id="cc" class="box">
    cc <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are prepending the wrong item. You need to prepend the parent `div` of the button, not the button itself. Also, you need to prepend to the `.wrap` div, which is the button's `parent parent` rather than to the button's parent which is just the `div` wrapping the button.

Lastly, you need to `focus()` on `this` (which is the button you clicked) to get the tab button working. At the moment you are not focusing on the button you clicked on.

See working example below:

```js
$('.btnTop').on('click', function() {
  let this_div = $(this).parent();
  this_div.parent().prepend(this_div);
  $(this).focus();
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap"> 
  <div id="aa" class="box">
    aa <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
  <div id="bb" class="box">
    bb <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
  <div id="cc" class="box">
    cc <button class="btnTop">Top</button>
  </div> 
</div>
```